# Is Enum Right For This?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm working on a `Model` and am using `enum` for a list of named items.

```
class Verse
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
class Chapter
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<Verse> Verses { get; set; }
}
class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
class Bible
{
    public Versions Version { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

enum Versions
{
    asv1901,
    bbe,
    darby,
    kjv,
    nasb,
    niv,
    nkjv,
    nlt,
    rsv,
    web,
    ylt
}
```

That seemed like a logical way to do it, but I'm finding that working with `enum` is adding unnecessary difficulty.

```
foreach (var chapter in chapters)
{
    var bibleitem = new Bible();
    bibleitem.Version = (Versions)Enum.Parse(typeof(Versions), chapter.version);
}
```

Would it make more sense to just use `string[]` or something?  I'm sure there is some added benefit, to `enum`, but I question my benefit.

Comment: What type is your `chapters` collection?

Comment: `enum` comparison is much more efficient that `string` comparison, enums are used for clarity of coding. To help you understand your code so fast.

Comment: You could use the generic [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.   `Versions ver; Enum.TryParse(chapter.version, out ver); bibleitem.Version = ver;`

Comment: What are “Versions”? Are they closer to “they have to be one of these predefined things and nothing else”, in which case they should be enums, or are they more like “anyone can make up anything they want here and whatever one person makes up has no relevance to what another person makes up”, in which case they should be strings.

Comment: Problem arises because in one place (`bibleitem.Version`) enum is used, but in another place (`chapter.version`) - string is used.

Comment: @NoelWidmer 'chapters` is `List<Chapter>` (but from a different class).  I make an API call (which uses its own model), it returns `JSON`, I `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, and then iterate through the resultant object (to create an `ObservableCollection<Bible>`.

Comment: But `Chapter` doesn't have a `version` property in your models...

Comment: @DourHighArch The different Bible versions are static.  They have to be those values, because those are the only versions that I have access to.  If a version of "JoJosVersion" was passed, it would result in a failure.  In that case, it does seem like `enum` is the right choice.

Answer (score 7):

The guidance from Microsoft is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In particular note: **Do not use an enumeration for open sets**

People write new Bibles all the time, so your set of enumerated values could change. You would be better off using string constants, for instance, where you could add more at will.

While we are at it, some additional critiques of your code.

```
class Verse
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Why is this a class, and why are the properties settable? Do you envision having an existing Verse in hand, and wishing to change its number and text to something different? If not, then don't allow it. I would write this as

```
struct Verse
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public Verse(int number, string text) : this() 
    {
      this.Number = number;
      this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Once it is created, it does not change. Also, this is a small immutable thing that is logically a value, so make it a struct.

```
class Chapter
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<Verse> Verses { get; set; }
}
```

Again, if you have an existing chapter, do you intend the set of verses to change? Because anyone can call `Add` on a list. Also, this constrains you to *having the list available at all times*, rather than computed lazily from a database. Make this `IEnumerable<Verse>`.

```
enum Versions
{
  asv1901,
  bbe,
```

This violates both naming guidelines and general legibility.  Spell things out!  `AmericanStandardVersion1901` is far better than `asv1901`.

Comment: Damn - Eric is here, my answer is doomed to not be noticed :P Hmm, why do you add a manual call to the default ctor?

Comment: @NoelWidmer: Because in previous versions of C# it was required, and now it is in my fingers to always do that. :-)

Comment: Didn't know that! VS has this formatting rule to prefix member access with `this.` automatically, you are doing the same. What is that good for? Solely for readability, or also a habit from old times.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the rationality of not adding to `Versions`.  I can understand if you code is set for numbers (`bibleitem.Version = (Versions) 4`), but my example shouldn't be affected.  Also, wouldn't adding to the end remove even that issue?

Comment: Why am I using `class`?  It's the only thing I know.  Hehehe...  I've seen `struct`, but I've never used it (not really sure how or in what cases).  I'm a hobbyist and never had any formal programming training (I do websites and app just to facilitate my own interests).  There is A LOT that I don't know.  Why are they settable?  Because I didn't know you could (or should) do it differently.

Comment: The only reason that I am using abbreviated version names is to match the strings that are coming from an API.  I figured it would be easier to work with, as opposed to doing some form of conversion.

Comment: @NoelWidmer: I usually add "this." even if it is not necessary. I think it's a good practice in that it makes the code readable. In cases where it distracts from the meaning of the code, I omit it.  I note that "this." is *required* if the method called is an extension method. As for using "this()" in a constructor: in C# 3.0 you had to invoke the default constructor to ensure that the hidden fields created for the properties were initialized. This restriction was removed in a later version; I don't recall which.

Comment: @doubleJ: The rationality is that if you write a `switch` that switches on all the Versions in v1 of your app, and then you add ten more versions in v2 of your app, *you have to remember to update every switch*, which is a point of possible bugs.

Comment: @doubleJ: A good rule to live by is: *don't let your users do anything that you did not design your system to allow*.  If there's no reason to make a property writeable, make it read-only. If there's no reason to make a list writeable, make it read-only. And so on.  It saves heartache in the future.

Comment: @doubleJ: If you're *naming something in a program* to match *its serialized format* then you are doing something wrong. Name things based on their meaning, not on their wire format, and then write code that translates between wire format and meaningful program elements.

Comment: I don't think "avoid open sets" is a particularly useful rule. There's very few sets of things in the real world which cannot change over time. Much more useful is having an analyzer which is aware of switch statements that are intended to be covering, and errors/warns if it no longer does so.

Answer (score 1):

You should use enums when you have a named list of constants in your code and you know that this particular list is not gonna change over time (hence called names list of constants).

what benifits do you get?
READABILITY. Using enums increases the readability of your code. Consider the scenario where I have 2 employee types: Permanent and ContractBased. Now I can do this in my code like this:

```
if employee.Type == 1
    // deal with permanent employee
else if employee.Type == 2
    // deal with contract based employee here
```

such code is hard to read and maintain as no one could guess what employee.Type == 1 or what employee.Type == 2 means.

If I define an enum instead like this:
    enum EmployeeType { Permanent=1, ContractBased=2 }

my code becomes like this:

```
 if employee.Type == EmployeeType.Permanent
     // deal with permanent employee
 else if employee.Type == EmployeeType.ContractBased
     // deal with contract based employee here
```

the readability of code gets maximized and also I have intellisense available.

The problem with strings:
1) you would end up having hard-coded string literals in your code
2) no intellisense
3) more memory consumption

how to deal with added complexity?
you should have an enum type variable for chapter.Version (which is right now missing) instead of int. that way you wouldnt need to do the parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `chapter.version` is coming in as a string (JSON API results).  What I want to do is put that string result into my collection.  Theoretically, the string result should only match one of those prescribed options.  Of course, it's possible that I'm looking at all of this incorrectly (I'm just a hobbyist coder).  I just use what seems right and try to make it all work.  Hehehe...

Answer (score 0):

```
but I'm finding that working with enum is adding unnecessary difficulty.
```

it depends on your needs. if your set will not change enum is the best way to go as it adds a more control with a verbose description and limited set that cannot be bypassed when you work with many developers on the same project.

**But**

if your set can change during the development of the solution and you can't preview the set than a string would be the better way to go

Answer (score 0):

Enums usually work best when:

1. No one adds or removes records to it anytime soon (hopefully never).
2. You don't need to use the real value behind your enum records.
3. You don't need to use the name of your records.

`Enum.Parse` can be used to get the enum record from a `string`, but as you noticed it's pretty ugly and I discourage you from using it. If you have the integral enum value you can simply perform a cast like this:

```
Versions version = (Versions)0;
```

But note that an enum is not guranteed to be of type `int`, it could also be any other integral value. `int` just happens to be the default. I do however also discourage you from relying on the enum's real integral value because something like this is also possible:

```
public enum Versions
{
   One = 1, 
   Two = 2, 
   Three = 3
}

public void Do()
{
   Versions version = (Version)-9;
   // version is now Versions.One.
   // Its value however is -9, what kind of version should -9 be?
}
```

The code above runs without errors because the runtime doesn't perform any checks on the value you are using for the cast.

**The answer to your question** depends on the nature of `Versions`. If you believe it will not be changed in the future then it is a good canditate for an enum in most cases. But you should use the enum everywhere across your application. I see in your sample that you are using the version as a `string` and therefore need to perform an ugly `Enum.Parse`. Consistency is an important factor when using enums, well it always is but it doesn't hurt to point it out again.

If you think your records are of a more dynamic nature you are probably best suited with `string`s. In that case you should use `string`s consistently. (Just wanted to point it out once again)

Comment: `chapter.version` comes in as `string` from a JSON API.  I guess I could use `switch` (to use the numbers), but that seems to add a bunch more complexity.

Comment: @doubleJ If you think your Versions will never change you can map your json strings to the enum with `Enum.Parse` (better use `Enum.TryParse`) but do it as soon as the json comes in and store enum instances instead of the json string. But as others have pointed out your `Versions` are probably subject of change which doesn't make them a good fit for using enums.

Answer (score 0):

using the enum  provides methods for comparing instances of this class, converting the value of an instance to its string representation, converting the string representation of a number to an instance of this class, and creating an instance of a specified enumeration and value.

Correcty using im class.

Exp.

```
public enum Versions 
{        
    asv1901,
    bbe,
    darby,
    kjv,
    nasb,
    niv,
    nkjv,
    nlt,
    rsv,
    web,
    ylt
}
```

Next, implement

```
foreach (var chapter in chapters)
{
     var bibleitem = new Bible();
     bibleitem.Version = (Versions) "Your class enum"(typeof(Versions), chapter.version);
}
```

Enum and more used for good programming practices, clean code

Referency using enum: [Enum Class Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx)